# React + Rollup package TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup

I have packaged some React ui elements that need to be reused in multiple packages into a separate package using rollup.

The package builds successfully and works fine in storybook, but when I use it in another package I get this error:

```bash
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at Object.useState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:377271:25)
    at HeaderProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:476314:54)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:242996:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:246282:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:247578:20)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:252541:18)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:251810:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:251733:9)
    at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:251706:11)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:251198:24)
```

```js
// rollup.config.mjs

const peerDepsExternal = require('rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external');
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('@rollup/plugin-commonjs');
const typescript = require('rollup-plugin-typescript2');
const postcss = require('rollup-plugin-postcss');
const svg = require('@svgr/rollup');
const url = require('@rollup/plugin-url');


const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default {
    input: "src/index.tsx",
    output: [
        {
            file: packageJson.main,
            format: "cjs",
            sourcemap: true,
            inlineDynamicImports: true,
        },
        {
            file: packageJson.module,
            format: "esm",
            sourcemap: true,
            inlineDynamicImports: true,
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal({
            includeDependencies: true
        }),
        url(),
        svg(),
        postcss(
            {
                inject: true,
                plugins: [
                    require('tailwindcss'),
                    require('autoprefixer')
                ],
                minimize: true
            }
        ),
        commonjs(),
        resolve({
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.svg']
        }),
        typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    ],
};
```

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.esm.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "plugin:storybook/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^8.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack": "^0.0.5",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^8.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "chokidar-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.14",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "rollup": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-react-svg": "^3.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-svg": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.36.0",
    "storybook": "^7.4.6",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.58",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried every possible way to change the way I import:

```js
import React from 'react';  // Failure

import * as React from 'react';  // Failure

import { useState } from 'react'; // Failure
```

it didn't lead to anything.

I found compiled code that equals this:

```
var Test = function () {
  console.log("REACT", {
    useState: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useState
  });
  (0,react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useState)("world");
  return (0,react_jsx_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.jsx)("div", {
    children: "Hello world"
  });
};
```

and I see normal console output:

```
REACT {useState: ƒ}
 > useState: ƒ useState(initialState)
 > [[Prototype]]: Object
```